# Embedding C++ program in Python GUI

Tags: python, c++, qt, user-interface, pyqt5

I've made a gui and am wondering how I would go about embedding a C++ program inside a section of the gui. So for example, from my MainWindow, if you click 'start game' a new window opens up with some graphical display, and the c++ game is embedded/executed within it. I've seen some articles about wrappers and using python in c++, but I don't have a good understanding of it, so I'm not sure that those apply to me in this case. If this is possible, should it be a .cpp or .exe? I'm more inclined to think it should be an executable file, but clearly I have no idea what I'm doing. I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: .cpp files are just text files... you need to compile you program into either an executable or a library for python to call

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution here is to create a standalone application in cpp that is simply called by your python gui with a system call: [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system). if you instead create a library (DLL) and wrap it into a python library with something like [swig](http://www.swig.org/) you can call functions directly and potentially wrap something like a GL renderer into a qt frame widget (if you want a 3d render widget this has been [done before](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) so don't waste your time re-inventing the wheel)

Comment: I already have the cpp,  is it just a one line call :os.system(path) or do I need to add something else so Python knows what to do with it? Sorry for such a 'hand-holding' question but I'm not at all familiar with it and need to have it ready in a couple of hours(if I can even manage). Thank you for your help.